# Linux USART Serial Port

Tags: linux, serial-port, uart

I'm trying to set up a USART serial port on a custom board with a SAMA5D36 processor, but I am unable to read in data from a connected device. When I run `setserial -g /dev/ttyS1` I get the following output:

`/dev/ttyS1, UART: undefined, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 22`

Now, I have seen a similar question ([linked here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217342/setserial-dev-ttys-uart-is-undefined)), but the solutions haven't worked for me. I'm wondering, can I not set the port up this way because it's USART not UART? Or does that not really make a difference?

As far as I can tell, the device tree is correctly setting up the port in the kernel, and I have configured the port as well as I can using `stty`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that it has a different name then ttyS1. On my device it has the name /dev/APP0. Check dmesg and /dev for other names.

Comment: I checked both, but it's definitely ttyS1. The MMIO address is the same as in the device tree.

Comment: Are you compiling your own kernel? Can you see the module load and the hardware initialize on system startup?

Comment: I am compiling my own kernel. Here's the output from dmesg:
`f001c000.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xf001c000 (irq = 22) is a ATMEL_SERIAL`

Comment: Looks like the module is loaded and hw is init. If you do a "cat /dev/ttyS1" while data is incoming, do you see anything? What are you using 'setserial' for?

Comment: Im reading up on setserial and it talks about "setserial deals with the lower-level configuring of the serial port, such as dealing with IRQs (such as 5), port addresses (such as 3f8), and the like." This is NOT something you want to do(?) because the device tree and the module has already done this.

Comment: When I do a "cat /dev/ttyS1" I don't see any data. My original thought was that since the setserial showed up undefined that meant there was a configuration issue, but it sounds like setserial isn't relevant.

Comment: There still could be a config issue, but it should be in the device tree or module used. Did you have to add this device (serial port) to your device tree or was it already there?

Comment: I don't believe it was added, though it's possible that people who worked on the system before me could have added it.

Comment: I recommend that this is where you start, the device tree. Verify that the correct hw address is used (uart0 vs uart1) and that the correct module is loading. Don't forget to check for device support (usart) in the kernel menuconfig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem, so I thought I'd share. It turned out that TX/RX were flipped in the schematic for the PCB, and I didn't figure this out until I checked the data sheet for the processor.

So, USART vs. UART is a non-issue, and `setserial -g /dev/ttyS1` returning undefined was an irrelevant distraction. Thus, to solve similar problems, verify device tree addresses (which were correct in my case) and verify pinouts on the hardware level (try swapping TX/RX even if you think they're correct). Also refer to the answers linked in my question.